# Is it possible/acceptable to publish the same article in 2 journals, if one is un-categorized?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

So as the title says I got the opportunity to publish my article right around the time my article has already been accepted by other **student** journal.

My question now is - is it acceptable to publish an article in both journals, with informing the editorial board first, if in the case of student journal I'm not getting any academic points for it?

I know that self-plagiarism is seen as publishing your paper multiple times in categorized journals to cheat the system for academic progression, but what is the general stand on an issue like in this case?

Comment: In principle it's up to the individual journal to decide this. They have their copyright rules that you can normally look up on their website. I don't know what exactly your definition of a "student journal" is, surely there is no official meaning to something like "getting any academic points" and I don't know what you mean by "categorized" - by whom and what categories? Chances are if it's a journal that is published by an officially established publisher, i.e., available everywhere in principle, they won't allow it.

Comment: Probably not. Don't waste energy worrying about pushing on this...

Comment: @Lewian, that is good enough to be an answer.

Comment: Actually "self plagiarism" means something different. It wouldn't be that. But let the journal editor decide whether they think it appropriate. Just give full disclosure to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It will most likely depend on the status of the "student journal". We had a "student journal" which was, officially, an archive of master theses in our program. As such, it is comparable to an archive of proceedings of a conference and does not prohibit submission to internationally recognized journals (or elsewhere) [in our field, "conference papers" do not exist - there are posters, but work presented on posters is usually later published in a journal paper without any issues].

Many of the papers published in this student journal ended up in high-ranked international journals without problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Most journals will not publish an article that's already published.**

Whether the student journal counts as published depends, e.g., informally compiled content may not fall foul of this. (Beyond whether publication is possible, consider whether you've submitted in parallel, which is forbidden by many journals.)

**Ultimately, it depends on the journals.**

Answer (score 0):

This question has a number of different components.

1. Does the 'student journal' permit you to republish the article elsewhere? Did you sign any license/copyright agreement with them?
2. Will a new journal be willing to consider your article, given that it has already been published? This will presumably depend on several factors, including (i) the details of what 'publication in the student journal' actually means, (ii) editorial policy, and (iii) the individual editor's interpretation of that policy. All you can do here is submit, explaining the situation fully and honestly, and see what they say.
3. What will the average reader think? Are people likely to come across both versions and regard this as 'naughty'? It is probably undesirable for people to form this opinion, even if you are convinced you are in the right. Again, this will depend on the details. For example, nobody questions the fact that the same text is often 'published' as both a masters thesis and as a journal paper, and in many fields preprint servers such as arXiv are becoming increasingly widespread. On the other hand, publishing identical texts in both Science and Nature would likely be seen as misconduct.